# Who built Juno's chipsets?

Tags: spacecraft, juno, flight-computer

Lockheed Martin was responsible for the construction of Juno.  But I was wondering who built the chips Juno uses for its onboard computers, and whether or not they are radiation hardened.  I would assume that, in addition to being in the vault, they are hardened.  Does anybody know where Lockheed got the chips themselves?

Comment: I suspect they use industrial grade, general usable microcontrollers. Considering the Lockheeds strong contact with the U.S. military they were produced by U.S. companies, despite that the chinese/south korean versions had been cheaper. On the software side, somewhere I've heard they use wxworks, but it is not a really uptodate info.

Comment: There likely is multiple suppliers. Each instrument will have it's own chips, which are likely different than others. Also, this kind of information isn't generally public domain.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Yes, I'm fairly certain this information is proprietary.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto That explains why I haven't been able to find any information about it on the web.  I'd think that the suppliers would at least be known.

Comment: @Phiteros Don't give up just yet. You got one answer, so you may at least get some partial information.

Comment: @peterh: no. Just about every spacecraft uses space-grade radiation-hardened components which have much more rigorous specs than industrial components.

Comment: Especially NASA/ Millitary ones, that tend to spend top dollar.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto -- Not SpaceX. They are using commercial off the shelf (COTS) computers,but  in large numbers. Single event upsets are not a problem. A rogue / malfunctioning computer is detected, restarted, and brought back in line. This results in a huge advantage in terms of vastly reduced cost and vastly increased computing power compared to rad-hardened computers that not so reminiscently bring one back to the previous millennium. However, this SpaceX concept might not work in a setting as hostile as Jupiter.

Comment: BTW, the given answer is 100% correct. Juno uses a RAD750 manufactured by BAE systems (actually a pair of them, for redundancy). It has the computing power of a 1999 personal computer, but with limited memory compared to a 1999 personal computer, and even more limited storage compared to a 1999 personal computer. Given Jupiter's extremely hostile environment, and given the time frame in which Juno's avionics were established, I doubt there was a better solution.

Comment: SpaceX uses rockets and stuff in LEO. I suspect the Red Dragon will use at least some rad hardened parts.

Comment: @DavidHammen ...and yet the [accelerometer chip is secret](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17055/#comment43654_17063)! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

BAE Systems is one supplier for the command and data handling processor.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAD750

> The RAD750 is a radiation-hardened single board computer manufactured by BAE Systems Electronics, Intelligence & Support.[[1]](http://www.baesystems.com/download/BAES_052281/Space-Products--RAD750-component) The successor of the RAD6000, the RAD750 is for use in high radiation environments experienced on board satellites and spacecraft.[[2]](http://www.ballaerospace.com/page.jsp?page=96) The RAD750 was released in 2001, with the first units launched into space in 2005.[[1]](http://www.baesystems.com/download/BAES_052281/Space-Products--RAD750-component)[[3]](http://www.aero.org/conferences/mrqw/2002-papers/A_Burcin.pdf)
>
> The CPU has 10.4 million transistors, nearly an order of magnitude more than the RAD6000 (which had 1.1 million).[[3]](http://www.aero.org/conferences/mrqw/2002-papers/A_Burcin.pdf) It is manufactured using either 250 or 150 nm photolithography and has a die area of 130 mm2.[[1]](http://www.baesystems.com/download/BAES_052281/Space-Products--RAD750-component) It has a core clock of 110 to 200 MHz and can process at 266 MIPS or more.[[1]](http://www.baesystems.com/download/BAES_052281/Space-Products--RAD750-component) The CPU can include an extended L2 cache to improve performance.[[3]](http://www.aero.org/conferences/mrqw/2002-papers/A_Burcin.pdf) The CPU itself can withstand 200,000 to 1,000,000 rads (2,000 to 10,000 gray), temperature ranges between –55 °C and 125 °C and requires 5 watts of power.[[1]](http://www.baesystems.com/download/BAES_052281/Space-Products--RAD750-component)[[3]](http://www.aero.org/conferences/mrqw/2002-papers/A_Burcin.pdf) The standard RAD750 single-board system (CPU and motherboard) can withstand 100,000 rads (1,000 gray), temperature ranges between –55 °C and 70 °C and requires 10 watts of power.[[3]](http://www.aero.org/conferences/mrqw/2002-papers/A_Burcin.pdf)
>
> The RAD750 system has a price that is comparable to the RAD6000 which is US$200,000 per board (per 2002 reference).[[4]](http://mae.pennnet.com/display_article/143464/32/ARTCL/none/none/1/BAE-Systems-moves-into-third-generation-rad-hard-processors/) However customer program requirements and quantities will greatly affect the final unit costs.
>
> The RAD750 is based on the PowerPC 750.[[1]](http://www.baesystems.com/download/BAES_052281/Space-Products--RAD750-component) Its packaging and logic functions are completely compatible with the PowerPC 7xx family.[[3]](http://www.aero.org/conferences/mrqw/2002-papers/A_Burcin.pdf)

http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/press_kits/JunoLaunch.pdf, page 15:

> **Command and Data Handling**
>
> Command and data handling includes a RAD750 flight
> processor with 256 megabytes of flash memory and
> 128 megabytes of DRAM local memory. It provides
> 100 Mbps total instrument throughput, more than
> enough for payload requirements.

Comment: Is FORTH still its machine language?