# When will SpaceX Falcon Heavy Tesla cross Mars orbit?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy, tesla-roadster

Elon Musk clearly miscommunicated here. The Tesla is going to take awhile to cross Mars orbit.  When will that be?

**note:** to future readers, the shape of the orbit shown in this tweet is no longer believed to be even close to correct. See answer(s) below for details on that.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That map seems to be quite wrong now. See this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25116/12102) and this [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24973/current-speed-of-tesla-roadster-which-is-moving-to-asteriod-belt/24981#comment72489_24973) and [Jonathan McDowell's tweet](https://twitter.com/planet4589/status/961394843648954368).

Until there is a better resource for finding Roadster on the internet (and there is one coming! (mentioned [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25078/12102)) I'll post this answer.

Using [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) and a [short Python script](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25079/12102) to plot it, I get the crossing about 154 days after 2018-Feb-08, or 2018-Jul-12. Coordinates are referenced to Roadster's projected position on `JD=2458311.5`. The thick red line is Mars' orbit and the thinner line is the Roadster projection, with dots at 145, 150, 155, and 160 days after 2018-Feb-08.

Note that the orbit in Horizons will probably be updated as more visual sightings are included, such as the one shown below.

[image]

**below:** DEMIOS image from [here](http://www.elecnor-deimos.com/deimos-sky-survey-spacex-starman-tesla/) as tweeted by Jonathan McDowell [here](https://twitter.com/planet4589/status/961700958030966784). The little dot near the center moving to the right and up is Roadster in reflected sunlight, probably mostly from the white FH 2nd stage still attached.

[image]